# Linq: GroupBy and Sum

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm having the hardest time wrapping my mind around LINQ .
I'm querying database

## date             ColumnC

25-04-2016          10

01-05-2016          8

10-05-2016          4

---

That I need to Group and Sum by year and month.

I tried to do this but it doesn't work :

```
public TYPE getX(DateTime value) {

var total = from p in context.table

         .Where(p => p.date.Year == value.Year)                    
                group p by p.date.Year into dp
                select new 
                {
                   
                    result = dp.Sum(s => s.ColumnC),
                    
                };
               

            return total;
}
```

i also could not know the return type.

---

in other words :

how to get a linq query from this :

```
select Month(date) Month ,sum(ColumnC) result

from table 

group by(Month(date))
```

==============

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have  result you have to cast your sum explicitly, therefore losing some data. This is necessary because your initial data is decimal. Therefore the code:

```
var total = (from p in context.table

        .Where(p => p.date.Year == value.Year)                    
            group p by p.date.Month into dp
            select new KeyValuePair<int,int> (dp.Key, (int)dp.Sum(s => s.ColumnC))
            );
```

The result of this will be `IQueryable<KeyValuePair<int,int>>` which is one way to also **know the type**.

Second option which is more correct would be not to cast the decimal to integer, therefore the code:

```
var total = (from p in context.table

        .Where(p => p.date.Year == value.Year)                    
            group p by p.date.Month into dp
            select new KeyValuePair<int,decimal> (dp.Key, dp.Sum(s => s.ColumnC))
            );
```

The result will be `IQueryable<KeyValuePair<int,decimal>>` which is pretty easy to work with.

In both cases the Key is the Month and the Value is the Sum of ColumnC

Comment: Exactly ...Thank you too

Answer (score 0):

Your return type here is partially *[anonymous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_type)*, which means you cannot ever know the type.

You can, however, directly retrieve the result as part of the grouping:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, decimal>> getTotalHeures(DateTime value)
{
    var total = from p in context.table
        .Where(p => p.date.Year == value.Year)                    
        .GroupBy(p => p.date.Month, p => p.ColumnC);

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the return type of my var is IQueryable<Deimal> , so i'm getting a conversion error : impossible to convert from IQueryable<Deimal> to IGrouping<int, int> , because we are selecting just one thing ( BTW : the columnC's type is decimal ) . Thanks again

Comment: I just notice you restrict to a certain year. So I modified to return only a single decimal which is the sum.

Comment: yes, but what i'm expecting is a query that return the sum for each month in that year . You can take a look of my table data if you want :)

Comment: This now returns groupings of month to the decimal column.

Comment: Fixed. Please do some of your own debugging!